# Prevent a jQuery mutation from being executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I have to execute two functions in jQuery when a mutation is triggered after clicking a button:

```
 function mutate(mutations) {
     mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
         function1().done(
             function2()
         );
     });
  }

 var target = document.querySelector('#identifier')
 var observer = new MutationObserver( mutate );
 var config = { characterData: false, attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false };
 observer.observe(target, config);
```

The code is working properly, but I was expecting that the mutation was fired only one time when I click a specified button; but for some reason the mutation happens twice, and then the code is executed twice too. I can't modify the code that triggers the mutation, so I can modify only the mutation handling (the code above).

Is there any way to prevent the twice execution each time? I should use a different method intead of forEach, but which one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without seeing what is changing in the DOM it's hard to say, but you can check exactly what the mutation was before you perform your logic (research the `mutation.type` property, for example). This will help you filter unwanted events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded a solution: when I click the button a node is removed and suddenly recreated. That's why I get two mutations.

I've added an `if` to make sure that the call is made only when the node is recreated

```
function mutate(mutations) {
     mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
         if(mutation.addedNodes.length > 0 && mutation.removedNodes.length == 0) {
             function1().done(
                 function2()
             );
         }
     });
}
```